# Indexing a multi dimensional array in Numpy

Tags: numpy

I'm a little confused on indexing in python. I have the following array

```
[[ 2  4]
 [ 6  8]
 [10 12]
 [14 16]]
```

and I want to obtain array([4, 2]) as my output. I tried using

```
Q4= [Q3[0,1],Q3[0,0]]
```

and my output come out as [4, 2]. I'm missing "array ("Any pointers on indexing in Python ? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just slice the 1st row reversed:

```
Q3[0,::-1]
```

---

```
array([4, 2])
```

Answer (score 1):

While one option would be to just wrap your result in another call to `numpy.array()`,

```py
np.array([Q3[0,1],Q3[0,0]])
```

it would be better practice and probably more performant to use [integer advanced indexing](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing). In that case, you can just use your indices from before to make one vectorized call to `numpy.ndarray.__getitem__` (instead of two independent calls).

```
Q3[[0, 0], [1, 0]]
```

Edit: [RomanPerekhrest's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75278135/2304905) is definitely better in this situation, my answer would only be useful for arbitrary array indices.

Comment: I think your example is more insightful for OP. +1

Comment: Thanks @Chrysophylaxs. It's definitely important to know both methods and recognize when you can use slicing vs. when to resort to integer indexing.